# Extract rows indices of TRUE

Tags: r

I have a df as

```
DF
1 FALSE FALSE
2 TRUE TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE
```

I want to extract row numbers which have only `TRUE`?
How can i do this?

Comment: TRUE, sorry. will correct

Comment: `which(rowSums(DF)==ncol(DF))`

Comment: Or ```which(Reduce(`&`, DF))```

Comment: @nicola Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 which((df[,1] + df[,2]) == 2)
 #[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
which(apply(df, 1, all))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check TRUE in both columns, use it bellow code:

```
which(df[,1]==TRUE & df[,2]==TRUE)
```

if you want to check TRUE in at least one column, use bellow code:

```
which(df[,1]==TRUE | df[,2]==TRUE)
```